# How to set limits and default params for photosphere?

Tags: aframe

I want to convert some old-school QTVRs to HTML5, and A-Frame seems to be just what I am looking for. But I can't figure out how to define parameters that were easy to configure in a QTVR .mov file. Specifically:

1. Some of my equirectangular images don't contain data at the zenith/nadir, so I would like to limit panning in the vertical direction so that these "holes" aren't visible when the user navigates inside the photo. Is there a way to restrict it (say to 160/-160, instead of 180/-180)?
2. I can't figure out how to set the default "center point" for the photo when it is initially loaded. I've been playing with rotation and phi-start and I successfully configured the initial "pitch" using both phi-start and rotation. But I'd also like to set the initial yaw (I want to point the camera down slightly for the default view), and when I use rotation for this, the photo gets distorted when you interact with it (the horizon is no longer level). How can I just set the initial view without distorting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You will need to modify your own controls if you want a customized feature like limiting the camera (which isn't good for VR). A good place to start is to copy and paste the A-Frame `look-controls` and customize to do what you need: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/components/look-controls.js
2. Playing with just the rotation should work. Open the A-Frame Inspector (`<ctrl> + <alt> + i`) and find a rotation that works.

Comment: How do you override built-in components? I tried copying / pasting look-controls.js into a custom component using the same name (as attempt to override it) but it results in an error that the component is already registered. So I tried using a unique name, and simply added a console.log inside init() to verify it's working, but it doesn't ever execute my console.log. I was able to get the simple hello-world Component to work, however, so I think I'm doing something wrong. Or are you suggesting I fork and modify look-controls.js (and create a custom build) to suit my needs?

Comment: Yeah, you fork and modify to a different named component (e.g., `restricted-look-controls`). You'll have to change the CommonJS/requires code to point to `AFRAME` global. Then attach it to your camera. `<a-entity camera restricted-look-controls>`

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I'm still having trouble getting even the baseline working. I'm using the "default" look-controls.js as a custom component, with required modules set to props / methods on the AFRAME global. The only thing I changed was to add a log in init() to confirm that it's getting attached (it is). But the photosphere is "locked" and you can't move around. Here's a link:https://glitch.com/edit/#!/fortune-quilt

Comment: Don't put the photosphere under the camera.

Comment: Here's a fully working example, using an added method to restrict panning to values set via html attributes: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/wry-rutabaga I was also able to set the initial view w/o distorting the photo by setting the rotation parameter on the camera entity instead of <a-sky>.